# Adding css property value to existing value with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change ul translate with JS

```
<ul id="navigation" style="-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);"></ul>
```

by clicking on button

```
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="pomakDesno()" class="button"/>
```

But when I change it using onclick I would like with every click to increase it, in otherwords, add some value to already existing value. I have this code. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script>
        function pomakDesno(){
        var mvalue=document.getElementById('navigation').style.WebkitTransform;
        var tvalue=111;
        var zvalue= mvalue+tvalue;
        document.getElementById('navigation').style.WebkitTransform='translateX(' + zvalue + 'px)';}

    </script>
```

Comment: Will you upload this to jsfiddle.net?  It's a great way and will speed up the time you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the number from inside `translateX(...)` in the original style.

```
function pomakDesno(){
    var mvalue=parseInt(document.getElementById('navigation').style.WebkitTransform;
    var translateX = parseInt(mvalue.match(/translateX\((\d?)px\)/)[1], 10);
    var tvalue=111;
    var zvalue= mvalue+tvalue;
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.WebkitTransform='translateX(' + zvalue + 'px)';
}
```